# NPOI SetColumnGroupCollapsed not working with SetColumnWidth

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi, npoi

Using C# and NPOI, I try to create an xlsx spreadsheet that groups a number of columns. The group should be expanded when the spreadsheet is opened. This worked, until I added custom column widths. If the column *directly after the group* has a custom width, the group opens in a collapsed state. Custom width in other columns causes no problem. Here's a minimal test function to reproduce:

```C#
            using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
            using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
            using System.IO;

            IWorkbook _workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            ISheet _worksheet = _workbook.CreateSheet();
            IRow row = _worksheet.CreateRow(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                ICell cell = row.CreateCell(i);
                cell.SetCellValue($"value of cell {i}");
            }

            // this line causes the group to open collapsed
            _worksheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 5500);

            _worksheet.GroupColumn(1, 2);
            _worksheet.SetColumnGroupCollapsed(2, false); // is default, should make no difference

            _workbook.Write(new FileStream(@"c:\\_temp\db.xlsx", FileMode.Create), false);
            _workbook.Close();
```

I tried to change the order of the GroupColumn and SetColumnWidth calls, but it doesn't change anything. I also tried to open an existing xlsx instead of creating it in the function. When that file was created by NPOI, like in the sample, the problem persists. When I open and save the file in libre office, on the other hand, the group opens expanded as expected.

[image: expected behaviour: group expanded]

I looked inside the xlsx files from npoi and office, but they are different enough to prevent a simple "it's this flag" answer. Am I overlooking something obvious?